# Adding a local scope to functions

Tags: javascript

I've gotten into the habit of adding the following at the top of all my functions:

```
var local = {};
```

That way, I explicitly scope all my variables.  For example:

```
for (local.i=0; local.i<x; local.i++) {} // local scope: good!
for (i=0; i<x; i++) {} // accidental global scope: bad!
```

Q: Is there a way to change the Function prototype to include var local={}; as part of it's definition?  That way I can assume that "local." means explicitly in the local scope.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this makes your life easier than explicitly using the var keyword. In either instance you need to remember to use a prefix, why not stick with the built in one?

Comment: Well, you can always try to use source code transformators, such as esprima. But I doubt you can do anything like this without code transformation.

Comment: How about just enabling [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) with `"use strict"`? That way, you get an error when you accidentally leak a variable into the global scope.

Comment: Wrap your for loop with a function, and don't forget the `var` keyword.

Comment: "...the following at the top of all my functions" : this shouldn't be needed as JavaScript variables have function scope (if you use `var` keyword). Using `var` is much more readable and "standard".

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what text editor you use for your work?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, you can't implicitly add a variable declaration and initialize it in every function scope (thank goodness). You need to manage your variable scopes manually, employing analysis tools when/if desired.

Imagine for a moment if this was possible. Any code you load could potentially corrupt any other variable scope, effectively defeating the purpose of scoped variables.

The `Function.prototype` will not help because prototypal inheritance has nothing to do with variable scope.

Your trick to protect `i` by putting it in a `local` object doesn't solve anything. It just moves the problem from the `i` variable  to the `local` variable, and still doesn't keep you from using `i` instead of `local.i`.

While including `"use strict";` can help by providing helpful error messages, you need to keep in mind that it changes behavior in some situations that can break code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this. You can't inject code into arbitrary functions and mess around with *their* local scope by changing the `Function.prototype`, and that's a *good* thing.

Besides, how would you *enforce* using the `local` object for local variables anyway? And how would you allow variable lookups through parent scopes, such as in:

```
function f() {
    var a = 5;
    return function g(b) {
        return a + b;
    };
 }
```

In your solution, you'd have a `local` object in the `f` and `g` functions, but the `local` variable in `g` would hide the parent's variable...

```
function f() {
    var local = { a : 5 };
    return function g(b) {
        // This declaration hides the parent's declaration
        var local = { b : b };
        // How would local.a be found?
        return local.a + local.b;
    };
 }
```

There's a much simpler solution to your original problem though: just enable strict mode with `"use strict"`. That way, you get an error when you accidentally leak a variable into the global scope. For example, your second sample would throw a `ReferenceError` when it tries to access the undeclared `i` variable (instead of creating a new global variable).

Do note that strict mode goes further than just preventing accidental global variables, [read up on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) so you understand the consequences!